# Умножение матрицы на вектор. C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, матрицы

Создал класс матрица и класс вектор. Как реализовать функцию умножения друг на друга их?

```
class Matrix
    {
    public:
        int **arr;
        int rows;
        int columns;
    public:
        Matrix() {};
        Matrix(int rows, int columns)
        {
            this->rows = rows;
            this->columns = columns;
            arr = new int*[rows];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = new int[columns];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    arr[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    };

class Vector 
    {
    private:
        int *vec;
        int size;
    public:
        friend Matrix;
        Vector(int size)
        {
            this->size = size;
            vec = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                vec[i] = 0;
            }

        }

};
```

Comment: "Матрица и вектор, как правило, не умножаются нацело." Веды.

Comment: @BuilderC Не знаю, как в Ведах, а в линейной алгебре "вектор, количество элементов которого равно количеству строк матрицы, может быть перемножен с этой матрицей".

Comment: А какие именно проблемы у вас с реализацией умножения?

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Спасибо, не знал. Теперь знаю, исключительно благодаря Вам. С другой стороны, у Вас написано: "может быть перемножен". Но ведь же может быть и не перемножен. Тогда как?

Comment: @BuilderC тогда операция не имеет смысла. Подобное перемножение, как правило, имеет смысл. Например, в физике гамильтониан (оператор полной энергии для волновой функции) можно представить в виде матрицы, а в виде вектора будет сама волновая функция и т.п. Разумеется, матрица и вектор будут при этом подходить друг к другу.

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov О, господи!!!

Answer (score 1):

Такое действие возможно, если имеется некоторая матрица matrix[m,n] и некоторый вектор vektor[n], количество элементов которого равно количеству строк матрицы. В результате получаем вектор new_vektor[n], первый элемент которого есть сумма произведений элементов первой строки массива matrix[m,n] на элементы массива vektor[n], второй элемент- сумма произведений элементов второй строки массива matrix[m,n] на элементы массива vektor[n] и т.д.

Не зная, какие у вас классы для матрицы и вектора, могу лишь предложить решение для массивов:

```
void MatrMultiply(int n, int m, float *matrix, float *vektor, float *res) // если необходимы целочисленные значения, можно заменить на int
{
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    float temp = 0;
    for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
      temp += matrix[i*m+j]*vektor[j];
    }
    res[i] = temp;
  }
} }
```

А дальше уж реализуйте аналогичное решение для своих классов.

Comment: Сейчас я постараюсь объяснить